# How can you center a gallery with html and css

Tags: html, css

I am quit new to html and css and hope someone can help.

With help of w3 schools (http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_image_gallery.asp) I created an simple gallery.

With this the images are put in the left upper corner. I want to put the images more in the central of the page.

Is there a way to easily do this?

Comment: @NullPointer - this question is solved with the answer below by Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap everything in a div with an id of `container`. Then add `#container { width: 100px; margin: 0 auto;` replacing 100px with how wide you want the gallery to be.

Comment: Thanks this works for putting it vertically in the center. Do you also know how I can centralize is horizontally?

Comment: That's generally a little trickier and if this is your first venture into CSS I wouldn't recommend it, but you can control how far it is from the top (specific amount) with `margin-top: 100px;`